# applet execution fail to execute batch file packaged inside executable jar

Tags: java, applet, executable-jar

I am executing a bat file through my java program. the path is hardcoded in java.

I have packaged bat file in the jar.and jar contains main class as an applet class.

i am calling this jar file from jsp page as applet.

applet run successfully but couldn't run bat file inside init.

If i give hard coded path then it executes ...but can't execute taking from jar.

Any hints for packaging such jar i.e having a bat file inside and able to run it as dynamic applet?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to make two impossible things here:

- execute a batch file from an applet. This would need a signed applet and permissions granted by the user, because obviously, launching an external program from an applet downloaded from the web is very very very insecure.
- execute a batch file which is not on the file system. cmd.exe expects the filesystem path of the batch file to execute. It won't be able to find the batch file in the jar which only exists in the memory of the browser. You would need to write the batch file to the file system (which, once again, would need a signed applet and granted permissions, because letting an applet writing on the local hard drive is very very insecure), and then execute this batch file.

Applets run in a security sandbox. You need to learn about it. Read http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html